# ionic serve not working with 'in app browser' plugin

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

When trying to use plugin 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser' ionic serve does not work

```
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error
    details.
```

This is my code:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

export class NoticeComponent {

  @Input() notice: Article;

  target: string = '_system';

  constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }

  openNotice(){
    this.inAppBrowser.create(this.notice.url, this.target);
  }
}
```

Try removing the node modules and reinstalling them but doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting anything in the console. Note that cordova plugins don't work in ionic serve

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```